# Developing R package, testing with `foreach`, while running simulations at same time with different package version

Tags: r, parallel-processing, devtools, parallel-foreach

I write almost all my R code in packages at work (and use git). I make heavy use of `devtools`, in particular short cuts for `load_all`, etc as I update functions used in a package.  I have a rough understanding of `devtools`, in that `load_all` makes a temporary copy of the package, and I really like this workflow for testing function updates in packages.

Is there a nice easy way/workflow for running simulations depending on the package, while developing it at the same time, without "breaking" those simulations?

I suspect there is an easy solution that I've overlooked.

Right now what I do is:

1. get the package "mypackage" up to a point ready for running simulations.  copy the whole folder containing the project.  Run the simulations in the copied folder using a new package name "mypackage2").  Run simulation scripts which include `library(mypackage2)` but NOT `library(mypackage)`. This annoyingly means I need to update `library(mypackage)` calls to `library(mypackage2)` calls.  If I run simulations using `library(mypackage)` and avoid using  `library(mypackage2)`, then I need to make sure the current built version of `mypackage` is the 'old' one that doesn't reflect updates in 2. below (but 2. below requires rebuilding the package too!).  Handling all this gets messy.
2. While the simulations are running in the copied folder I can update the functions in "mypackage", by either using `load_all` or rebuilding the package.  I often *need* to **Rebuild** the package (i.e. using `load_all` without rebuilding the package when testing updates to the package isn't a workable solution) because I want to test functions that run small parallel simulations with `doParallel` and `foreach`, etc (on windows), and any functions I modify and want to test need the latest built "mypackage" in the children processes which spawn new R processes calling "mypackage".   I understand that when a package is built in R, it gets stored in `..\R\R-3.6.1\library`, and when future R sessions call `library(mypackage)` they will use that version of the package.

What I'd ideally like to be able to do is, in the same original folder, run simulations with a version of `mypackage`, and then update the code in the package while simulations are stopped/started, confident my development changes won't break the simulations which are running a specific version of the package.

Is there a simple way for doing the above, without having to recopy folders (and make things like "mypackage2")?

thanks

The issue described here is sort of similar to what I am facing [Specify package location in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503708/specify-package-location-in-foreach)

The problem is that if I run a simulation that takes several days using "mypackage", with many calls to `foreach`, and update and rebuild "mypackage" when testing changes, future `foreach` calls from the simulation may pick up the new updated version of the package, which would be a disaster.

Comment: The solutions in the other question you linked to don't work for you? Why?

Comment: @Alexis The other question's answers would work if I wasn't trying to develop the package at the same time as running simulations (that could take days to run if interrupted). If i'm changing the package code and rebuilding, while other scripts are running the simulations (that call `foreach` and spawn new R processes that load the latest version of the package in the libraries folder), I think there is the risk any child R processes in the simulation break because they reflect the changes in the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answers in the other question do apply,
but you need to do some extra steps.

Let's say you have a version of the package you want to test.
You'd still create a specific folder for that version, but you leave it empty.
Here I'll use `/tmp/mypkg2` as an example.
While having your project open in RStudio, you execute:

```
withr::with_libpaths(c("/tmp/mypkg2", .libPaths()), devtools::install())
```

That will install that version of the package to the provided folder.

You could then have a wrapper script,
say `wrapper.R`,
with something like:

```
pkg_path <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1L]

cat("Using package at", pkg_path, "\n")

.libPaths(c(pkg_path, .libPaths()))

library(doParallel)

workers <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(workers)

# We need to modify the lib path in each worker too
parallel::clusterExport(workers, "pkg_path")
parallel::clusterEvalQ(workers, .libPaths(c(pkg_path, .libPaths())))

# ... Your code calling your package and doing stuff

parallel::stopCluster(workers)
```

Afterwards, from the command line (outside of R/RStudio),
you could type (assuming `Rscript` is in your path):

```
Rscript path/to/wrapper.R /tmp/mypkg2
```

This way, the actual testing code can stay the same
(including calls to `library`)
and R will automatically search first in `pkg_path`,
loading your specific package version,
and then searching in the standard locations for any dependencies you may have.

Comment: @mpirie Do note that you would have to adjust lib path every time you create workers with `makeCluster`, so if your package's functions do that, they'd need access to `pkg_path` and some special treatment accordingly, at least during development.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your use-case (as to why you want to do this) but what I normally do when testing two versions of a package is to push the most recent version to my `dev` branch in GitHub and then use `devtools::load_all()` to test what I'm currently working on. Then by using `remotes::install_github()` and specifying the dev branch you can run the GitHub version with `mypackage::func` and the devtools version with `func`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  What happens when you want to use say `foreach` (with more than 1 core), and the code called in foreach depends updates to your package code?  The code in foreach will still be using your last build R package version (and won't reflect any changes you do in `load_all`).  Meanwhile you are running other R scripts that take hours/days to complete and they depend on your 'original' package version before your recent updates

Comment: To be honest this is a specific use-case which I am unfamiliar, I can't get my head around why you're using `foreach` for testing, can't you re-run `load_all`?

Comment: Specifically, I'm testing functions in "mypackage" that will be calling `foreach` inside them ... inside the `foreach` call, only `mypackage::func` will get called. any changes to `func` won't be reflected inside those `foreach` calls. This is why i have to build the package when testing the new version of the package